# How can I clone an attached object of EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

How can I created a detached copy of an attached object I've got from the entity manager?
I don't want to detach the original one, I want to create a copy of it while making sure that changes on the copied object won't effect the database.
I need to copy the attached object since it contains changes which were not yet written to the database.
Afterwards I want to continue and working with the attached object (and do more changes).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this so can't guarantee it'll work, but you can try something like this (`em.detach()` available since JPA 2.0)

```
MyEntity m1 = em.find(MyEntity.class, 1);
em.detach(m1);
MyEntity m2 = em.find(MyEntity.class, 1);
```

`m2` should be attached, while `m1` remains detached.